# VB Script code to read column value from lotus notes database

Tags: vba, lotus-notes, lotus, names

```
Set domSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Dim domDatabase 
Set domDatabase = domSession.GetDatabase("server Name", "xyz.nsf")
Set domView = domDatabase.GetView("All Projects")
```

Up to here it's ok. But I try lot but unable to read the document values.

I am looking for the vbscript code to read the document data.

Comment: The answer depends on what is in the column.  If it is a simple field value from a document, then the method @PanuHaaramo gave will work -- although please see my comment regarding the inneficiency of getNthDocument in large views. But if the column contains calculated values, then the answer would have to be different.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Right, I didn't notice until now that the title says "column value". I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
Dim i%
Dim s$
Dim doc As Object

For i% = 1 to domView.EntryCount
  Set doc = domView.GetNthDocument(i%)
  s$ = doc.GetItemValue("itemname")(0)
  ' Do whatever you want with the string value which is now stored in s$
Next
```

This code assumes the items are text type. You could use simply `Dim s` to get any item type (number, date).

To get column values from the view you can use `doc.ColumnValues(2)`. This returns the value of 3rd column (0 is first).

Comment: GetNthDocument has very, very poor performance if there are a lot of documents in the view.  It would be much better to use a while loop and use getFirstDocument and getNextDocument.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Actually it's the fastest way to traverse view documents.

Comment: No, I'm sorry, but it is not.  This has been well covered in talks about the Notes object model given by IBM engineers at conferences for well over a decade as well as in numerous articles over the years.  Just do a google search on "getNthDocument performance".  The top hits include titles like "Don't use getNthDocument" and "avoid getNthDocument".  And this IBM technote is the top hit:  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21099588

Comment: @RichardSchwartz I went to those conferences too and saw misinformation being presented :-) The technote talks about DocumentCollection for which your statement is true. Test it yourself. Last time I tested (which was a while ago!) it was like I said. The difference is not very big though.

Comment: It's not as simple as what I implied, and yes... I forget that there are cases where getNthDocument is faster.  I shouldn't be as absolute about it.  But for general advice, I'm going to trust Bob Balaban's word because he wrote the classes in the first place and knows what (still) goes on inside them.  See the slide labeled "Myth 10" here.  http://www.bobzblog.com/tuxedoguy.nsf/dx/BP114.pdf/$file/BP114.pdf
I may test this myself, but I was planning on jumping into the argument about whether columnValues() is better than getItemValue() that's been going on on the notes.net forums first ;-)

Comment: @Rich: What, no multitasking? ;-)

Otherwise I agree with Rich, never encourage the use of GetNthDocument. Even if there might be some case where it is as fast or even slightly faster than GetFirstDocument/GetNextDocument, most developers (especially the beginners that post questions about it) knows WAY too little about different kinds of collections (sorted vs unsorted) to be able to use it only in the right case.
So even if they save 2-3 seconds in one particular case, they will lose minutes in other places because they use the same method in the wrong place. Make it easy, just never use it.

Comment: LOL. You beat me to the punch on testing ColumnValues() @Karl-Henry.  I still might do it, though.

Comment: In support of my friend Richard, we used my likeness for the character of GetNth Doc on the CULT shirt 2003. "The GetNth Doc - Kills patients--but not because he's evil, he just moves 
too slow to save them."